# Gradle assumes wrong Nodejs version after updating React Native

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, gradle

### Problem

I tried to update to the newest React Native version 0.73.1 and after executing the neccessary steps and trying to launch the app, I get this error:

> Script '/app/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle' line: 391

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

> React Native needs Node.js >= 18. You're currently on version v16.20.2. Please upgrade Node.js to a supported version and try again.

I use *nvm* and am on version 21.5. Why does it assume the wrong version? I already tried:

- delete node_modules and reinstall
- gradlew clean
- resync project with Gradle

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the output of `node --version` when you are in project directory

Comment: @tayyab-mazhar It is v21.5.0